# Is there any way to change FilterMode of custom Sprite in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, texture2d

I'm making 2D pixel graphic game and want to use custom Sprite using Texture2D class.
So I used code like this:

```
Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, size, size), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 32)
```

But this created sprite has FilterMode "Bilinear". I want to change it to "Point (no filter)".
Changing FilterMode in inspector is very easy but I don't know how to change it in runtime. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can only change the filter mode of the texture.

```
texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;

Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, size, size), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this but it doesnt really seem to work. Nor does setting the filter mode of the texture before Sprite.Create.

```
spriteRenderer.sprite.texture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
```